# Mosaic Layer as input for Mosaic Dataset Configuration Script

Tags: arcgis-pro, mosaic-dataset

In the ArcGIS Pro GUI and with ArcPy, I can add a Mosaic Layer (a Mosaic Dataset dragged to the contents area) to another Mosaic Dataset with Add Rasters and Raster Type Table.
The reason I want to do this is that I want to import only a subset of items. I select these with arcpy.SelectLayerbyAttributes(), the expression being Name IN (list of element numbers). As it's name indicates, the function only works with Layers, so I need to turn the Mosaic Dataset into a Mosaic Layer before applying it.

For now I create the Mosaic Dataset with arcpy instead of MDCS.
Another workaround could be a join of the mosaic dataset with the selection table?

`arcpy.management.AddRastersToMosaicDataset("input_mosaicDS", "Table", "Mosaic_layer")`

Is there a way to do this with the config file of an MDCS. When I put

````
<AddRaster>
    <dataset_id>DTK_$land$_$datum$</dataset_id>
    <raster_type>Table</raster_type>
    <Sources>
          <data_path>mosaic_layer</data_path>
    </Sources>  
</AddRaster>```

the Mosaic dataset is emtpy. I can create a MD in arcpy and then import it into antoher with MDCS, but of course it would be more elegant importing the layer directly.
````